# How to iterate over list-of-list, and accumulate product of two fields

Tags: python, list, idioms

I have written some simple Python code that should select the second element of each list within the main list and provide the user with a sum of all of these values. It should also multiply the second and third elements of each list within the main list and then sum these values.

However, when I attempt to run this code I am confronted with a

```
list index out of range
```

error.

```
usa_univs = [ ['California Institute of Technology',2175,37704],
          ['Harvard',19627,39849],
          ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology',10566,40732],
          ['Princeton',7802,37000],
          ['Rice',5879,35551],
          ['Stanford',19535,40569],
          ['Yale',11701,40500]  ]

def total_enrollment(usa_univs):
    a = 0
    c = (len(usa_univs)) -1
    while c > 0:
        a = a + ([c][1])           
        b = b + (([c][1])*([c][2]))
        c = c - 1 
    print (a,b)


print total_enrollment(usa_univs)
```

Comment: It's not a bad question. The mistake here is basic, but what OP is trying to do (iterate over list-of-list) is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a *new* list with just one element every time, then indexing that:

```
[c][1]
```

With only one element, that indexing will fail. If `c` is an index into the `usa_univs` list, you do need to reference the list:

```
usa_univs[c][1]
```

However, rather than manually manage indexes into that list, use a `for` loop to access each element *directly*:

```
a = 0
b = 0

for element in usa_univs:
    a = a + element[1]
    b = b + (element[1] * element[2])
```

where I also set `b` to 0 (you forgot that part), and `c` is no longer needed at all.

Python lets you *unpack* sequences into their constituent parts; you can do so even in the `for` loop:

```
for name, a_value, b_value in usa_univs:
    a = a + a_value
    b = b + (a_value * b_value)
```

and you can use [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) to make adding to `a` and `b` a little more compact:

```
for name, a_value, b_value in usa_univs:
    a += a_value
    b += a_value * b_value
```

In the end your function should use *`return`* rather than printing. Leave printing to the *caller*; you already do so but your function now returns `None`. Your whole code, with all these improvements, then looks like:

```
usa_univs = [ ['California Institute of Technology',2175,37704],
          ['Harvard',19627,39849],
          ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology',10566,40732],
          ['Princeton',7802,37000],
          ['Rice',5879,35551],
          ['Stanford',19535,40569],
          ['Yale',11701,40500]  ]

def total_enrollment(usa_univs):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for name, a_value, b_value in usa_univs:
        a += a_value
        b += a_value * b_value
    return a, b

print total_enrollment(usa_univs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[c][1]
```

or

```
[c][2]
```

You need to use this syntax:

```
usa_univs[c][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `usa_univs` before `[c][1]` and the like. You also need to initialize `b`, otherwise you will get a reference-before-assignment error in `b = b + ((usa_univs[c][1])*(usa_univs[c][2]))`.

Although not very elegant, this should work:

```
def total_enrollment(usa_univs):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = (len(usa_univs)) -1
    while c > 0:
        a = a + (usa_univs[c][1])           
        b = b + ((usa_univs[c][1])*(usa_univs[c][2]))
        c = c - 1 
    print (a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

As, it has be said you forgot to use usa_univs[c][1]

Also, use simple pythonic **for** to iterate over each element( without having to worry about the indexing), and access the individual element

```
def total_enrollment(usa_univs):
  a = 0
  b = 0
  for data in usa_univs:
    a += data[1]
    b += data[1] * data[2]

  return a,b

print (total_enrollment(usa_univs))
```